# Connection to localhost:5432 refused after docker run when port 5432 is clearly open and listening?

Tags: spring, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a ci service (specifically gitlab ci, if it matters) that is docker-compose'ing a postgres instance at `0.0.0.0:5432` which is then needed for maven integration tests I run within a dockerfile.

For some reason, and you can see the stack trace, the dockerfile maven integration tests can't connect to the container open on 5432.

Why is this happening and how do I fix the connection?

FWIW, when I run `docker-compose up` and run the integration tests locally (as opposed to within a dockerfile) everything passes fine.

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
28d4ca05dd26        postgres:12.3       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   27 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   ************db_1
$ docker run --name ************ ************
```

```sh
07-07-2020 20:46:01.634 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
07-07-2020 20:46:02.721 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1670)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$before$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:192)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
07-07-2020 20:46:02.765 [main] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
07-07-2020 20:46:03.472 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logMessage - 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
07-07-2020 20:46:03.531 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### will update with answers

> Have you tried checking if you flushed the iptables rules that docker created? if so restart docker service, and double check the iptables rules: iptables -nvL

```sh
$ iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

> What OS are you running? is SELinux in enforcing mode? getenforce if so check if something got denied: grep -i denied /var/log/audit/audit.log

```sh
$ cat /etc/*release
3.12.0
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.12.0
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.12"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
```

> I don't think this is a pg_hba.conf but it does not hurt to check the config.

I'm not sure how to do that?

> ## test with telnet in you can mannualy connect: telnet localhost 5432

```sh
$ telnet localhost 5432
telnet: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

> As a last resort while running docker-compose up watch a tcpdump: tcpdump -nni any port 5432 maybe the traffic got redirected somewhere, or localhost is badly defined in /etc/hosts

```sh
$ tcpdump -nni any port 5432
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
```

#### when i try different host

**application properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/*****************db
```

```sh
08-07-2020 16:24:57.484 [main] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: The connection attempt failed.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : The connection attempt failed.
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because if you are using docker compose to expose a service port, you need to connect to the `service name` instead of localhost

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

If the name of your service is `postgres` just point your app to `postgres:5432`

Comment: sounds promising ill give it a try

Comment: still getting an error when changing the host to the docker-compose service name

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried checking if you flushed the iptables rules that docker created? if so restart docker service, and double check the iptables rules: `iptables -nvL`
2. What OS are you running? is SELinux in enforcing mode? `getenforce` if so check if something got denied: `grep -i denied /var/log/audit/audit.log`
3. I don't think this is a pg_hba.conf but it does not hurt to check the config.
4. test with telnet in you can mannualy connect: `telnet localhost 5432`
5. As a last resort while running `docker-compose up` watch a tcpdump: `tcpdump -nni any port 5432` maybe the traffic got redirected somewhere, or localhost is badly defined in /etc/hosts

Comment: edited post with answers to all of your questions (that i knew how to answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the reason . I am running on Windows 10. Here is my whole logs:

```
xaxage@DESKTOP-S29VKBP:~$ docker run --name student-management -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:al
pine
41d6e33448cf7b67c9ac5f96c5b1109f625e4803a6d861bd510f8c5018c42b05
xaxage@DESKTOP-S29VKBP:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
41d6e33448cf   postgres:alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds   0.0.0.0:2454->5432/tcp   student-management
xaxage@DESKTOP-S29VKBP:~$ docker exec -it student-management
"docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
See 'docker exec --help'.

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container
xaxage@DESKTOP-S29VKBP:~$ docker exec -it student-management /bin/bash
bash-5.1# psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
bash-5.1# psql -U postgres
psql (14.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \q
bash-5.1# psql -U postgres -p 2454
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.2454" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
bash-5.1# psql -U postgres --port=2454
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.2454" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
bash-5.1# psql -U postgres -W
Password:
psql (14.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE  studentmanagement;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \l
                                     List of databases
       Name        |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-------------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 studentmanagement | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=#
```

As you can see i wrote port as 5432:5432 but idk why in next line it writes "0.0.0.0:2454->5432/tcp" . So my true port was 2454. Ant this helped me. Also before it i deleted postgress app on my windows , dont know if these are connected.